# how to extend express js res object in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express

Here is a simple route:

```
// get all users
app.get('/api/user/get-all', authenticated.yes, function(req, res) {
    queryUsers.findAllUsers( function( users ){
        res.json( users );
    } );
});
```

The output would be the json returned from the "queryUsers.findAllUsers" function.

This is great, but i want to route all my json output through something more rigid so the output would be:

```
res.json({
    success: true,
    payload: users
});
```

This is really easy to do manually but means I have to write this out each time which is a lot of typing.

Is it possible to add new functions to the "res" object, to enable something like this:

```
res.jsonSuccess( users );
```

and:

```
res.jsonFail( users );
```

Which would output

```
res.json({
    success: true,
    payload: users
});
```

and:

```
res.json({
    success: false,
    payload: users
});
```

respectively.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As loadaverage pointed out, middleware is how you do it. For some more specificity:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    res.jsonFail = function(users) {
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            payload: users
        })
    };

    res.jsonSuccess = function(users) {
        return res.json({
            success: true,
            payload: users
        });
    };

    next();
});
```

and then this should work:

```
app.get("/my/route", function(req, res) {
    return res.jsonSuccess(["you", "me"]);
});
```

Comment: Ahhhh i get it now! The penny drops. Thank your very much :D

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I want to extend current method with new method.
For example, log everything that I sent.

This what you can do:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var _send = res.send
    res.send = function (data) {
      console.log('log method on data', data)
      // Call Original function
      _send.apply(res, arguments)
    })
})
```

Comment: Now. I didn't. `apply` gets array of arguments. and `arguments` is al the arguments that the `send` got. I want after doing our method to run the original method with the same `arguments` . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can write some simple [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use), then app.use(yourmiddleware) just like usually.